# Getting value's position on a new row ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

I am paging my data in groups of 100 using `LIMIT`. So in the query below we have the 5th page of Prince songs ordered by Filename:

```
SELECT Song_Title, Artist_Name, `Record_Company`, Filename
FROM songs 
WHERE songs.Filename != ''  AND Artist_Name LIKE '%Prince%' 
ORDER BY songs.Filename ASC LIMIT 400, 100
```

What I need to do is find the position of a row given the ordering of the query.

So in the example below Controversary by Prince is in positon 2 because it is ordered by Filename.
But if I order it by Song_Title is will be in position 1. I will be able to use this value as a pivot so if the display is re-ordered by a different column the user can keep the value already selected displaying.

Here's an attempt at that query:

```
SELECT Song_Title, Artist_Name, `Record_Company`, Filename, **ROW_NUMBER**
FROM songs 
WHERE songs.Filename != ''  AND Artist_Name = 'Prince' AND Song_Title = 'Controversy'
ORDER BY songs.Filename ASC
```

Here's an example of the table layout:

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------+
|Song_Title | Artist_Name|`Record_Company`|Filename|
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------+
|   Kiss    | Prince     |   WARNER       | a      |
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------+
|Controversy| Prince     |   WARNER       | b      |
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------+
|  Cream    | Prince     |   WARNER       | c      |
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------+
```

Obviously I can do this by querying every row and just finding the positon in memory but given how many rows I have returning this is not a viable option. 
Is this possible in SQL?

Edit:

The output I'd like to see would be just the row or row number of the selected value. I will use that to know what Page I should set my limit too.

Edit 2:

Mysql version: 5.6

Comment: Please also show us the exact output you want to see.

Comment: Ok @TimBiegeleisen Is that sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, you could directly use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```
SELECT Song_Title, Artist_Name, `Record_Company`, Filename,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Filename) rn
FROM songs
WHERE Filename != '' AND Artist_Name LIKE '%Prince%'
ORDER BY Filename
LIMIT 400, 100;
```

If you want to find a given record from the above result set, while also retaining the row number we computed, then you will have to subquery:

```
SELECT Song_Title, Artist_Name, `Record_Company`, Filename, rn
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Filename) rn
    FROM songs
    WHERE Filename != '' AND Artist_Name LIKE '%Prince%'
    ORDER BY Filename
    LIMIT 400, 100
) t
WHERE Song_Title = 'Cream';
```

If you need the above query in earlier versions of MySQL, then use this:

```
SELECT Song_Title, Artist_Name, `Record_Company`, Filename, rn
FROM
(
    SELECT *, @row_number:=@row_number +1 AS rn
            FROM songs
    WHERE Filename != '' AND Artist_Name LIKE '%Prince%'
    ORDER BY Filename
) t, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS r
WHERE Song_Title = 'Cream';
```

Comment: Cool answer! Thanks! Is this possible with MySql 5.6? I forgot to add my MySql version sorry.

Comment: @Jerome I gave an edit for earlier versions of MySQL, targeting the 'Cream' record while retaining the row number computed earlier.

Comment: Okay. The last one worked! I needed to make an edit though. Do you mind if I change your answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this for giving row number in mysql:-

```
  SET @row_number = 0;
  SELECT  (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS Slno, Song_Title, Artist_Name, `Record_Company`, Filename
  FROM songs 
  WHERE songs.Filename != ''  AND Artist_Name LIKE '%Prince%'  AND Artist_Name = 'Prince' 
  ORDER BY songs.Filename ASC LIMIT 400, 100
```

if you want to assign row number according to the group then you may try this:

```
  SET @row_number = 0;
  SET @groupnumber = 0
  SELECT  @row_number:=CASE
    WHEN @groupnumber = groupnumber THEN @row_number + 1
    ELSE 1
  END AS num,
  @groupnumber :=groupnumber as groupnumber ,
  Song_Title, Artist_Name, `Record_Company`, Filename
  FROM songs, (SELECT @groupnumber :=0,@row_number:=0) as t 
  WHERE songs.Filename != ''  AND Artist_Name LIKE '%Prince%' 
  ORDER BY songs.Filename ASC LIMIT 400, 100
```

Comment: Cool answer! thanks. This could get me every prince song on page 4. Is there a way to know which numeric value Cream By Prince is without returning the whole set?

Comment: if you know the filter in your case which is `prince`, why don't you directly apply this filter on your record and get the data only for `prince`.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen was able to get the answer I needed.  Thanks for your answer anyway.